# How to find a specific between table HTML tags RegEx

Tags: regex

I want to find a RegEx that allows me to find a specific text between HTML table tags.
I have: `This is a test text <tr><td>text inside table</td></tr>` and I want the RegEx to return me just the second '**text**' because it is inside the table.

I have tried `<tr>(text)<\/tr>` but returns nothing.

It needs to be done with RegEx it cannot be done with a HTML parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<tr>(text)<\/tr>` matches only `<tr>text</tr>`, but you have other text around.

So you need [`<tr>.*?(text).*?<\/tr>`](https://regex101.com/r/p8KRep/1) for that